# Can we use angular without routing in MVC5

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing, asp.net-mvc-5.2

Can we use angular in asp.net mvc without using its $routeprovider, as in i want to use angular in few pages without having to register the routes is it possible to have so.

In short can we use angular in some pages and not in others in asp.net mvc.

Comment: did you tried to use it? did you had a problem with using it like that?

Comment: yes tried in pages calling the ng-app separately and there controllers, it is working though, i was thinking for a solution where i can have a single ng-app and then use angular without routing for few pages

Comment: not sure what you want to do. You can have partial routing with angular if you like for these few pages only. is that what you are after?

Comment: i did not want to use angular routing was the question for me, but anyways  having separate app initialization also sorted my issue.
Can you help me out with partial routing with any example.

Comment: with partial I mean `example.com/angular/(any)` this will be handled by angular, while all others handled by `asp.net` . You have to configure your router in the server so that any url after `angular` will redirect to the same page, where your `app` is initialized. sorry I have no experience with `asp.net mvc` to be more precise

Answer (score 0):

yes you can. you can specify a specific controller per page ( and even per html element )

for example a page 1 :

```
<div ng-controller="myController1">
 ...
</div>
```

a page 2 with another controller:

```
 <div ng-controller="myController1">
 ...
 </div>
```

Comment: thanks,
but in page 2 i do not want to use angular if i am redirecting from page 1 and also i donot want to use angular routing